# ASP.NET Core with React.JS How to open separate Browser for the Backend?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've created an "**ASP.NET core with React.Js**" project :

[image]

And when I'm running it, it waits a while then redirects me to the front-end page which makes me not able to have the back-end browser(I need it to play with **SwaggerUI** and other stuff):
[image]

**The question is:**
how can I make both browsers open? I mean a browser for the front-end "http://localhost:46432" and one for the back-end as well "https://localhost:7211".

And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download NuGet dependecy:

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Adding the following lines to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
...
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

then from the browser call the backend URL+swagger: https://localhost:7211/swagger